# Pyspark: Overwrite parquet file failed for spark sumbit job

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs

I used **spark-submit** to run my pyspark codes and wanted to overwrite an existing file in HDFS. However, it kept failing and the error message is

> 17/10/27 10:18:07 java.io.FileNotFoundException: File does not exist:
>   hdfs://path_to_my_file.parquet/part-00116-acbec1f9-7293-41b4-98f7-1c45167b9941.snappy.parquet

My code

```
df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").save("hdfs://path_to_my_file.parquet")
```

However, I am pretty sure that the file does exist before the overwrite function and when I passed the same codes in the console, it worked! Really dont understand it and how should I solve this issue.

I am using Spark 2.1 and Python 2.7

Comment: You have to check permission into HDFS or check your path. It might be /user/file.

Comment: in my system it doesn't need "hdfs://" because by default it takes hdfs local as default path. try this too.

Comment: It works. So it is the problem of permission?

Comment: no. for default path there is no need to add "hdfs://".

Comment: okay, but when I read the parquet file, it is okay to add the "hdfs://" and when I write.mode("append"), it is also fine. only happens when I want to overwrite